# Android: Getting bundle string to create sqlite database table

Tags: android, sqlite

Thanks for your time in reading my question.

I plan to write an app that allow the user to select the table columns to perform a full text search. Therefore, I get the user input into bundle string and try to pass this into the SQLiteOpenHelper. However, the SQLOpenHelper is unable to get the string. My code snippet is as follows:

```
ActivityA.java
public class ActivityA extends Activity {
...
//get the selected dropdown list value
public void addListenerOnButton(final Spinner sp1, final Spinner sp2, final MultiSpinner msp1, final MultiSpinner msp2) {

btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

//@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    strpkey = String.valueOf(sp1.getSelectedItem());
    strskey = String.valueOf(sp2.getSelectedItem());
    stronscreen = String.valueOf(msp1.getSelectedItem());
    strwhenclick = String.valueOf(msp2.getSelectedItem());

    Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Pkey", strpkey);
    bundle.putString("Skey", strskey);
    bundle.putString("Onscreen", stronscreen);
    bundle.putString("Whenclick", strwhenclick);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
      startActivity(intent);                                
}
```

Note: I am able to get the bundle string in ActivityB so I don't think the problem lies in ActivityA.

```
ActivityB.java

public class ActivityB extends Activity {
public String strpkey, strskey;
public String stronscreen;
private DbAdapter dbHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.countsheet);

    strpkey = getfilepath("Pkey");
    strskey = getfilepath("Skey");
    stronscreen = getfilepath("Onscreen");

    Toast.makeText(this, strpkey + " " + strskey + " " + stronscreen, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    dbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
    dbHelper.open();

public String getfilepath(String strbundletext) {
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String csvpath = bundle.getString(strbundletext);
    return csvpath;
}
...
}
```

DBAdapter.java

```
import com.ksgrp.stocktake.ActivityB;

public class DbAdapter {

public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public ListDesign csobj2 = new ListDesign();
    public String pkey = csobj2.strpkey;
    private String skey = csobj2.strskey;
    public String onscreen = csobj2.stronscreen;        

    private String getstr(String pkey, String skey) {
        ActivityB csobj = new ActivityB();
        String pkey = csobj.strpkey;
        String skey = csobj.strskey;
        String onscreen = csobj.stronscreen;

        String sqlstr = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + vdb_tbl + " USING fts3(" + sqlstr + ")";
        return sqlstr;      
    }


    //@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String strsql = getstr(this.pkey, this.skey);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + vdb_tbl);
        db.execSQL(strsql);
        Log.w("TAG", strsql);
    }
}
```

I get a java null pointer exception when I click the button in ActivityA:

```
03-08 14:04:31.569: E/AndroidRuntime(29573): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ksgrp.stocktake/com.ksgrp.stocktake.ActivityB}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: vtable constructor failed: stocklist2: CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE stocklist2 USING fts3(null, null)
```

I believe I am unable to get the value in the bundle string into the DBAdapter class. Can anyone give me a hand on this? I can provide the full code (but it is lengthy so I have just extracted the relevant bits above).

Comment: I remember having same issue, can you change these statements to       intent.putExtra("Pkey", strpkey);
    intent.putString("Skey", strskey);
    intent.putString("Onscreen", stronscreen);
    intent.putString("Whenclick", strwhenclick);

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I don't think the problem lies in the intent.putExtra statements as I am able to show the Toast if I comment out the database statements

Comment: I think I see what is wrong String sqlstr = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + vdb_tbl + " USING fts3(" + sqlstr + ")", you are passing sqlStr as fields, it is wrong. You need to pass columns you are getting as parameters. See this link http://blog.andresteingress.com/2011/09/30/android-quick-tip-using-sqlite-fts-tables/

Comment: Can you be specify? I have changed the intent statements in ActivityA.java as follows but the same error still exist:        Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setClass(ListDesign.this, CountSheet.class);
  
    intent.putExtra("Pkey", strpkey); 
    intent.putExtra("Skey", strskey);
    intent.putExtra("Onscreen", stronscreen);
    intent.putExtra("Whenclick", strwhenclick);

Comment: I provided a link with example. It is with your sqlStr string. Please check.

Comment: thanks, I have amended the sqlstr as: String sqlstr = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE stocklist2 USING fts3(" + this.pkey + ", " + this.skey + ")"; but problem still exists:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ksgrp.stocktake/com.ksgrp.stocktake.CountSheet}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: vtable constructor failed: stocklist2: CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE stocklist2 USING fts3(null, null); The error message show my sqlstr outcome. It looks ok except that I cannot get the value of pkey and skey.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should try to retrieve selected value of spinner in `` ` and not ``onButtonClick`.

So, instead of `strpkey = String.valueOf(sp1.getSelectedItem());` in `onButtonClick`,

try

```
sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

           strpkey =sp1.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
           }
```

and use this `strpkey` directly in `onButtonClick`.

Similarly for other 3 spinners.

Hope it helps...